# Dynamic memory allocation issue when copying to new array

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory

I am creating a function to split a char * into an array of other char * based on a target (which can be " ", "a", etc). In this example, I am using  a white space (" ") to split my char * into an array of char *.

However, I am having some difficulties dealing with the dynamically allocated memory. I allocated memory for both the array of char * that I will be returning as the split function return value, and another one to copy each separated const * that I am reading from the main char * parameter.

```
#define MAX_SIZE 65535
#define MAX_SPLIT_SIZE 1023

char** a_split(char * x, const char * target, int sn){

    char ** sa = nullptr;

    size_t t_len = strnlen(target, MAX_SIZE);
    if(t_len < 1 || t_len > MAX_SIZE){ return sa; }

    int split_num = 0;

    if(sn > 1 && sn < MAX_SPLIT_SIZE){

        sa = new char * [sn + 1]();
        split_num = sn;


    }else if(sn == -1){

        sa = new char * [MAX_SPLIT_SIZE + 1];
        split_num = MAX_SPLIT_SIZE;
    }else {
        return sa;
    }

    char * ptr = x;
    char * mi;                                              // Match index.

    int i = 0;                                              // Index of 'sa' array.

    while((mi = std::strstr(ptr, target)) && split_num--){

        size_t dif = mi - ptr;

        char * n_cstring = new char[dif + 1]();

        memcpy(n_cstring, ptr, dif);                        // Copying content to new string.

        sa[i++] = n_cstring;                                // Append new string to 'sa' array of split strings.

        ptr += dif;

        ptr += t_len;

        delete [] n_cstring; // <------- This is causing some weird errors.
    }

    if(mi == nullptr){

        sa[i] = ptr;
    }

    return sa;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    char  c[] = "I love Thanos";

    char ** x = a_split(c, " ", -1);

    for(int i = 0; x[i]; i++){
        puts(x[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I found out that when using 'delete [] n_cstring', instead of outputting the char *'s separately (like in "I" "love" "Thanos"), it is outputting "love" "love" "Thanos". It is making this kind of repetition for every example. Why is 'delete' doing this?

Also, as I am returning a dynamically allocated array ('sa'), where would you recommend me to delete it? - the main function does not recognize 'sa'.

Comment: How about using `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: "a const *" is not a thing. Please clarify what you're talking about. `const` is an adjective.

Comment: When you say `char* x = new` ... I read that as `std::string x;` without the need for delete or the need to worry about its size

Comment: "*the main function does not recognize 'sa'*" - If you don't understand function calls and return values yet, I recommend staying away from dynamic memory allocation for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you are deleting `n_cstring` too soon: since you are storing it in `sa[]` array, i.e.

```
sa[i++] = n_cstring;
```

deleting it right after that in the loop leaves `sa[i]` hanging. The end result is that your `main` would have undefined behavior, in addition to having memory leaks due to never deleting `sa`.

> I am returning a dynamically allocated array (`sa`), where would you recommend me to delete it?

There is only one place where this could be done - it's `main`. You put `sa` into `x`, so you need to invoke `delete[] x` once you are done printing.

Note that since `delete[] n_cstring` must be removed from `a_split` function, `main` must also delete the individual elements of `x` before deleting `x` itself.

The best approach by far is to change your code to use `std::vector<std::string>`. This would free you from allocating and deleting character arrays, fixing potential crashes automatically.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo That's because you didn't set `sa` elements to `nullptr` after the allocation inside `a_split`. The parts that you did allocate will be deleted normally, but once you hit the first uninitialized "junk" element you'll see "deleting memory that has not been allocated" error.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo Yes, `main` must delete what has been allocated, and that is what your `for` loop does. The problem is that your `for` loop does not stop after deleting what's been allocated, because extra cells inside `sa` (aka `x`) contain uninitialized junk.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo Your approach is right. Make sure you set all `sa` to `nullptr` right after the allocation. If the error remains, run your code with valgrind to see what else is going on.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo If you delete only `x`, you have a memory leak. Did you try running valgrind? You can download it [here](http://valgrind.org/downloads/current.html#current). This tool is essential for memory profiling.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo Put your `for` loop back into `main` and try valgrind again. This time you will see the problem.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo Does valgrind tell you anything about invalid de-allocations or invalid access? That's the only thing I can imagine that would lead to a crash.

Comment: @MauriceFigueiredo Look for the error on stack overflow, there are many questions on "how to fix an XYZ error reported by valgrind".